# How to support DIV validation instead of FORM?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I really liked [this](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) bootstrap form validator. I wanted to make changes to it so that it can validate a **div** tag, not only **form**.

For example, this is how it works:

```
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
    ...
</form>
```

So you must have a **form** tag with **data-toggle="validator"**.

What I would like to do is instead make this work on any **div** tag with **data-toggle="validator"**, like so:

```
<div data-toggle="validator" role="form">
    ...
</div>
```

However, no matter what I do to [validator.js], validator never works the same.

I thought that I could do a search for **"form"** inside of [validator.js] and replace it with **"div"**, here are the instances and changes:

I changed:

```
.filter('[form="' + this.$element.attr('id') + '"]')
```

To:

```
.filter('[div="' + this.$element.attr('id') + '"]')
```

I also changed:

```
// VALIDATOR DATA-API
// ==================

$(window).on('load', function () {
  $('form[data-toggle="validator"]').each(function () {
    var $form = $(this)
    Plugin.call($form, $form.data())
  })
})
```

To:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $('div[data-toggle="validator"]').each(function () {
    var $form = $(this)
    Plugin.call($form, $form.data())
  })
})
```

Still not working the same as original code. The rest of the code seems to use base .form-control classes to look for form elements. I am unsure where else to look. Any thoughts on this?

### Original code without changes: (HTML + JavaScript):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="container">

        <form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.5/validator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense, semantically, to validate a `div`. Forms are meant to encapsulate form fields and provide validation and submission. Is there a reason you want to do this different from, you know, the way browsers were built to handle?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan for example where you may have a nested form like in sharepoint where every page has an enclosing form thus all your custom forms would be divs.